# What we can deduce about the truth of the case $B$

Tags: logic

Assume that we have the following implications between two case $A$ and $B$: $$¬B⇒¬A$$ and $$¬B⇒A$$

Here $¬B$ is the **negation** of the case $B$.

My **question** is: What we can deduce about the truth of the case $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $B$ is false. Then $\neg B$ is true and so both $A$ and $\neg A$ hold by assumption, a contradiction. Thus $B$ must be true.